# Nexus3 and S3 bucket do not mirror each other's artifacts (in synch)

Tags: amazon-s3, nexus, blobstore, nexus3

We have fired up a dockerized Nexus3 and map our S3 bucket (s3 Blobstore)

> Scenario:  User uploaded a jar file in customed Host Maven 2 repo that
>   we have created e.g. sample-maven-repository. User was able to upload
>   the jar file and the content was uploaded in S3. However, user deleted
>   the jar file which he uploaded recently and it was successfully removed. We
>   can no longer see the jar file in the "Browse" section of Nexus3 UI.
>   The problem is the content is still in S3 bucket.

Is there any way that when we delete the jar file in Nexus3 UI, it will be automatically deleted in S3 bucket?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components deleted from NXRM3 are not automatically deleted from the blobstores intentionally, they are "soft deleted" so that if you deleted by accident they can be restored.
On a file system blobstore, you need to compact blobstore task to fully delete.
On S3, final deletion is handled by the AWS Lifecycle.  To my knowledge it not possible to configure automatic deletion using that but you might be able to tweak it to close to what you want (or others may know of configurations I do not).

Comment: This has given me light on my problem. Thank you @joedragons